# Why can't I reserve two contiguous memory regions in the same allocation without reserving both with a single call?

Tags: c++, winapi, memory-management, allocation, virtual-memory

I have two memory regions I'm allocating with `VirtualAlloc`: `0x1E0000 (Size: 0x39000, Reserve)` and `0x219000 (Size: 0x3000, Commit)`. These are both within the same allocation boundary (which in this case is rounded to `0x40000 (64K*4)`), and the second region starts where the first ends.

Now forget the commit part for a minute. If I `MEM_RESERVE` the first `0x39000` and then `MEM_RESERVE` the next `0x3000`, I get `ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS`. However, if I `MEM_RESERVE` both in one go, `0x39000+0x3000=0x3C000`, then it works, and I can use `MEM_COMMIT` to commit the second region successfully.

Why is that? Why can't I reserve each part on its own instead of as one big reserved region? After reserving the first region the remaining area within the allocation `(0x219000-0x21FFFF)` will have the `MEM_FREE` state, so how come I cannot reserve the first `0x3000` of the remaining `0x7000` in the allocation boundary?

Comment: Post your commented code. I is difficult to follow what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have two separate reservations within the same allocation boundary.

From the documentation for VirtualAlloc:

> lpAddress [in, optional]
>   The starting address of the region to allocate. **If the memory is being reserved, the specified address is rounded down to the nearest multiple of the allocation granularity.**

(emphasis mine)

So your request to reserve memory starting at `0x219000` actually attempts to reserve memory starting at `0x210000`, which is inside the existing allocation and hence illegal.

(It should also be noted that there is no guarantee that any particular region of virtual memory will be available for you to reserve; Windows may have already reserved it for some other purpose.  Best practice is to always set the `lpAddress` parameter to `NULL`, allowing Windows to choose an address for you.)

Answer (score 1):

By making two reservations you are requesting that the system manage them separately however as you note they are within the same allocation boundary so are likely being managed as a single unit. If you request a part of that unit the other part just goes unused.

However if you reserve them together you are requesting they be managed together so splitting isn't necessary.

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887(v=vs.85).aspx) for the method:

> The starting address of the region to allocate. If the memory is being reserved, the specified address is rounded down to the nearest multiple of the allocation granularity.

So your second one actually reserves starting at the same location as the first.